# jQuery ajaxForm trigger file upload on file drop over div

Tags: jquery, ajax, upload

I use jquery form plugin for ajax file upload, which looks like this:

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" id="form" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="upfile" size="44" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="upload" value="Upload" enabled>
  </form>
```

Next this magic makes it work:

```
// ... lots of option for begin, progress, complete events ...
$("#form").ajaxForm(options);
```

Now to the question, I want to use onDrop event to handle file upload,
that what i have so far:

```
dz.addEventListener('drop', function(e){
  FileDropHandler(e); // to prevent file download
  $('#dropzone').removeClass('over');

  var files = event.dataTransfer.files;
  alert(JSON.stringify(files[0]));

}, false);
```

So now, how do I tell ajaxForm to use dropped file for upload?

Answer (score 0):

After the file drag and drop, save the variable `files` so it's accessible from your `ajaxSubmit` later. Then simply send it as [extra data](https://github.com/malsup/form/#data)

```
$(this).ajaxSubmit({
    data: {files:files}
})
```